# What is the maximum amount of data that a browser (for example: Chrome) can store in cache?

Tags: google-chrome, caching, browser

I am working with a PBI report, which is accessed via browser. I could see the query to load the report gets cached when accessed first which allows second load faster. However, if I do multiple interactions (selecting slicers, filters and opening child reports) and opening other 2-3 reports and performing same above actions and then return back to the very first report, I could see the query request are being triggered again, instead of loading it from the browser cache. Which means I might have reached the cache limit.

Please note the query request of my reports itself doesn't have any **Cache-max age** headers in the response.

I am expecting that it has some kind of cache limit set (may be general for all browsers). If its set, What is that value? Could I alter that value to increase browser cache? ?

From Chrome browser , Cache settings I could see the max amount of cache size of images and files is always within 320MB. Is this the common limit for all browsers ??

Answer (score 4):

**Cache size**

Cache functions differently for different browsers. There is often not a clear "rule" for each browser, and the cache limit and functionality can differ between devices and browsers.

You stated that the max cache size was 320MB. This may always be true for your device, but if you check on a different device or configure different settings, this will change. Chrome often uses cache sizes larger than 320MB, and can even get into a gigabyte depending on the users hard drive space. Microsoft Edge and Firefox function very similarly.

Safari is a bit more cloudy in cache, as it is given constraints by iOS to optimize device performance. Firefox also uses dynamic cache, but is configurable (described below), and you can track its size more clearly than Safari cache.

**Increase cache size**

You can increase the size of your cache on Chrome. You cannot adjust the size of the cache for an end user on any of the common browsers.

For Chrome, you can change the local cache easily using the following these steps:

1. Launch Chrome
2. Right click on the Chrome icon
3. Right click on the line item that reads "Google Chrome"
4. Click on "Properties"
5. Navigate to the "Shortcut" tab
6. Click on the "Target" box
7. Add this to the end of the line: `—-disk-cache-size=524000000`

On windows, this will now read `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disk-cache-size=524000000`

This will set the cache to *approximately* 524MB, but it will likely not be that value, as described [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DiskCacheSize); Chrome takes it as a "hint" to what cache size should be. It may seem desirable to increase this to a massive value, but there will be diminishing returns, and if you go too large you may actually inhibit performance.

To change cache size on Firefox refer to [this article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1272857#:%7E:text=Now%20look%20for%20%27%27%27browser,KB%2C%20before%20restarting%20Firefox%20again).

You can change the cache size in Microsoft Edge through a GUI as described [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-microsoft-edge-cache-size-in-windows-10).

**Headers**

You said that you are not setting `Cache-Control: max-age` as a header, but it would likely be beneficial to do so. For example, if you want the cache to persist for 24 hours, you could do `Cache-Control: max-age=86400`. Keep in mind that you may encounter issues if you are loading dynamic content but are telling the browser to keep content around for a full 24 hours. If you have truly static content, you could cache it for as long as you want; conversely, truly dynamic content will often be set with `Cache-Control: max-age=0`.

**Optimize PBI Reports for Cache**

If caching is important to you, you can design your PBI reports accordingly.

1. Use aggregations to reduce the amount of data that needs to be queried and transferred
2. Optimize queries by pre-calculating measures
3. Minimize data size by excluding irrelevant data
4. Use the Performance Analyzer to understand which parts of your PBI report are using the most resurces

Answer (score 0):

I think you can configure that cache size. This is as per Chrome documentation. You can get more info [here](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/#DiskCacheSize).